# Minimum integer solution to some system of congruences involving prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Consider some system of congruences
$$ 
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned} 
x &\equiv r_1 \pmod {p_1} \\
x &\equiv r_2 \pmod {p_2} \\
&\;\;\vdots \\
x &\equiv r_n \pmod{p_n} 
\end{aligned}
\right. 
$$

Where $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n$ are the first $n$ prime numbers.

Suppose that the system has a solution, and thus the general solution can be found using the Chinese remainder Theorem. My question is: is there some method to systematically find the minimum integer solution to the system? If not, is there at least some method to find some lower bound, and how sharp?

Thanks!

Comment: You can find an arbitrary solution $N$ of the system in the usual way. Then $N \text{ mod } p_1p_2\cdot \dots \cdot p_n$ is the least nonnegative solution of the system.

Comment: Also, the chinese remainder theorem guarantees that there is a solution (which is unique modulo the product of the above primes)

Comment: Thanks! If you want to post your comment as an answer, you are welcomed!